# what kinds of errors popen record

Tags: c

I am trying to execute the command `"adb tcpip 5555"` in cmd and get the output to use it in another statement.

This adb code should give `error: no devices/emulators found` but the buffer remains empty.

```
FILE* lsofFile_p = popen("c:\\adb tcpip 5555" ,"r");
char* line_p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), lsofFile_p);
printf("\n***\nbuffer = %s***\n\n", buffer);
pclose(lsofFile_p);
printf("\n***\nbuffer = %s***\n\n", buffer);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`popen()` returns `FILE*` to the `stdout` of the command you run. So, if you want to read `stderr` (it looks like the command you run gives errors that goes to stderr), then
you could do redirect stderr to stdout:

```
FILE* lsofFile_p = popen("c:\\adb tcpip 5555 2>&1" ,"r");
```

Be aware that this will mix `stdout` and `stderr`. So, there's no way to differentiate output and errors, if that matters.

Comment: thanks that works, but well you define the meaning "2>&1"

Comment: `1` is stdout and `2` is stderr file descriptors. So, `2>&1` says "redirect stderr to wherever stdout goes to".